# Inserting multiple rows in one table from two other tables

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert

I need to insert multiple rows into a table with one query (instead of using looping, which is possible, but a huge waste of server resources.)

I have three tables:

```
-Members
MemberID (int)

-Items
ItemID (int)

-MemberInventory
MemberID (int)
ItemID (int)
```

When I add a new member, I need to select that new memberID and ALL of the itemIDs and insert them into the MemberInv table.

When I add a new item, I need to select that new itemID and ALL of the memberIDs and insert them into the MemberInv table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a INSERT SELECT for max(memberID ) and CROSS JOIN Items

```
  insert into  MemberInventory ( MemberID, ItemID )
  select t.max_id , Items.ItemId
  from (
    select  max(Members.memberId) max_id
    from members
  ) t 
 cross join  Items
```

Comment: The response from the database: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'cross join  Items' at line 3

Comment: update your question and show me the exact query you are using

Comment: insert into  MemberInventory ( MemberID, ItemID ) 
    select  max(Members.memberId), Items.Items
    from members
    cross join  Items


This works (it was missing the 'from' line) but it only inserts one line, the first one. I need it to insert ALL of the lines from items

Comment: try the new version

Comment: That's it! Thank you!! I'll reverse it for adding a new item to all of the old members.